# How to get React warnings in Parcel React extension

Tags: reactjs, parceljs

I have a Chrome Extension built with Parcel and React, but I'm not getting warnings (e.g. missing `useEffect` dependencies) when I inspect the popup. How do I get these warnings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing `useEffect` dependencies warnings are provided by [eslint](https://eslint.org/) through [this plugin](https://github.com/facebook/react/tree/main/packages/eslint-plugin-react-hooks). Parcel won't run eslint for you unless you set it up through the `@parcel/validator-eslint` plugin. I provided instructions on how to do that in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71375095/how-do-i-configure-parcel-to-exit-build-with-an-error-if-eslint-does-not-validat/72130037#72130037).

Another option is to use `eslint-watch` ([npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-watch)) from the command line separately from parcel, so you'd have two separate scripts in your `package.json` that might look like this:

```
{
   "scripts": {
      "start": "parcel src/index.html"
      "lint": "esw --watch src/**/*.js"
   }
}
```

To get react hooks warnings, you'll need to use [`eslint-plugin-react-hooks`](https://github.com/facebook/react/tree/main/packages/eslint-plugin-react-hooks) by first installing it (e.g. `yarn add eslint-plugin-react-hooks --dev`), and then adding this to your `.eslintrc.json`:

```
{
  "extends": [
    // ...
    "plugin:react-hooks/recommended"
  ]
}
```