# Parcel: Call eslint script on save

Tags: eslint, parceljs

I have configured eslint so that when I run `npm run lint` I get lint errors. How do I configure Parcel so that it runs this command when my code is saved?

Comment: This is pretty similar to [the other question you recently asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72103413/how-to-get-react-warnings-in-parcel-react-extension), and I think I answered both of your concerns there.

Comment: How can I get eslint to watch and log errors in the same terminal panel that I run `npm start` in?

Comment: [my answer to your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72130372/4739687), has a link to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71375095/how-do-i-configure-parcel-to-exit-build-with-an-error-if-eslint-does-not-validat/72130037#72130037) which explains how to set up `@parcel/validator-eslint`, which can do this.